# SQL: change value in field to equivalent

Tags: sql-server

Pardon me if my question is utterly simple but SQL isn't really my strongest suit and I'm failing at google and SO isn't suggesting anything useful here...

If I had a table in SQL (SQL Server) that had a state column where yahoos were putting in anything they wanted and it was my job to clean it up and standardize the inputs (ignoring people who put numbers, countries, etc in the state column), how would I go about checking for those entries that actually fit a normal profile so that it could be converted to the two letter state abbreviation?

Say for example:

```
AddressID   UserID  StateProvince   CountryCode
536         17      Oregon          US
537         18      Washington      US
```

And I want to convert those states to their appropriate state abbreviations....

There is currently another table which lists all the administrative divisions and their abbreviations like so:

```
ID      StateProvinceCode   CountryCode Name
1       AL                  US          Alabama
2       AK                  US          Alaska
```

I imagine something similar to (psuedo)

```
UPDATE Address
    SET StateProvinceCode=
    Case StateProvinceCode
        WHEN 'Alabama' THEN 'AL' 
        WHEN 'Alaska' THEN 'AK'
        ...
    END,
WHERE CountryCode = 'US'
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following update query to do this simple task :

```
UPDATE ADDRESS 
SET StateProvince = B.StateProvinceCode
FROM ADDRESS AS A INNER JOIN STATES AS B ON A.StateProvince = B.NAME
```

No need to write any case statements for this using this techique.

Comment: you might want `ON upper(A.StateProvince) = upper(B.NAME)` to be safe.

Comment: @Hogan Sql server is case insensitive by default as per my knowledge so query should match state names properly i guess. But yeh, still to make sure we can convert both columns in upper case.

Comment: The upper case was actually a requirement. I just tested this on the dev db and it works beautifully. You guys are awesome.

Comment: Great, Thanks. I might missed that.

Comment: @HirenDhaduk - Right standard collation.  Been using DB2 to much recently :)

Comment: Got it. I am working with sql server and mysql so. I think mysql is case sensitive, not sure though. So my query will be fail in case of mysql i think. :(

Answer (score 0):

you could join in your `divisions` table `on table.StateProvince  = divisions.Name` and update `StateProvince` to `StateProvinceCode`

```
UPDATE table
SET StateProvince = StateProvinceCode
FROM table INNER JOIN 
divisions ON 
StateProvince = NAME
WHERE 
CountryCode = 'US'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.StateProvince = d.StateProvinceCode
FROM Address a
  join AdministrativeDivisions d
    on a.CountryCode = d.CountryCode
      and a.StateProvince = d.Name
WHERE 
  a.CountryCode = 'US'
```

If StateProvince in Address doesn't match with AdministrativeDivisions.Name then value won't be updated, so you'll change only 'normal profile'.